# How to select a record which have all id's in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want select record which have all id's.

Example:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Ram | 3 |
| Ajay | 1 |
| Mogan | 3 |
| Ram | 1 |
| Ram | 2 |

Here Ram have all id's (1,2,3). So, I want result as Ram.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database platform you are using (and version).

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE(NAME,CODE)AS
(
  SELECT 'RAM',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT'AJAY',3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MOGAN',2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'KUMAR',3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'RAM',2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JAYA',1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'KABIL',3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'RAM',3
)

SELECT C.NAME
FROM CTE AS C
GROUP BY C.NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C.CODE)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CODE) FROM CTE )
```

As far as I know, this is called "relational division". You can try my query or look for another possible solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table where upper(name) = 'RAM'
```

This query would bring back all the IDs for RAM alone

Comment: This will work for the limited dataset in the question, but won't scale out to larger datasets where `name` is something onther than `'RAM'`.

Comment: So therefore you want to group the names and see the values? Example RAM and all its values then AJAY and all its values

Comment: Can you give a better example? How your vision of it?

Comment: Add 3 records with 'Sam' as `name` and 1, 2, and 3 as `ID`.  I imagine the OP would want to also then return 'Sam' as well as 'Ram'.

Answer (score 0):

how about string agg.

```
   CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(255),
);

Insert into MyTable(ID, Name) values (1, 'Ram');
Insert into MyTable(ID, Name) values (2, 'Ram');
Insert into MyTable(ID, Name) values (3, 'Ram');
Insert into MyTable(ID, Name) values (1, 'Ajay');
Insert into MyTable(ID, Name) values (1, 'Mogan');

select Name, string_agg(ID, ',') as Ids
from MyTable
group by Name;
```

result

```
Ajay    1
Mogan   1
Ram 1,2,3
```

see result here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/923bf/4

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the with clause used by @surgey above,

```
WITH CTE(NAME,CODE)AS
(
  SELECT 'RAM',1 from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT'AJAY',3 from dual  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MOGAN',2 from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'KUMAR',3 from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'RAM',2 from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JAYA',1 from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'KABIL',3 from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'RAM',3 from dual
)
select name, code, rank() over(partition by name order by code) rank
from cte
```

this query, it will bring back everybody in the and group them by name. THis could be one possible solution other use tou can use an "IN" clause in your where as shown below

```
Select * from table where upper(name) in ('RAM','AJAY')
```

Answer (score 0):

If are you using MySql this will solve your issue:

```
SELECT r1.name
FROM raws r1
LEFT JOIN raws r2 ON r1.id = r2.id AND r1.name = r2.name
WHERE r2.id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP by r1.name
HAVING count(r2.id) = 3; # count of numbers in IN (1, 2, 3)
```

And if you have identifier in your table use it for join instead
of `r1.id = r2.id AND r1.name = r2.name`